# Face Recognition approach DCT features

Tags: algorithms, pattern-recognition

[Face Recognition approach based on entropy
estimate of the nonlinear DCT features](http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1312/1312.1520.pdf) proposes to use maximum entropy estimate of the DCT of the pixels. My question is maximizing entropy would mean minimizing information content since entropy is negative to information. So, how come the Authors say that maximum entropy means maximum information? Can somebody please help in clearing the confusion regarding their techniue ? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The high entropy features are those that have different values in different samples. A feature that has 0 entropy is a feature that has always the same value. So features with more entropy can give you more information about the individualities of each image, instead of giving you an information present in all of them. 
What the article says about high frequency DCT coefficients can be also said about high entropy features: "the high frequency components are related to unstable facial features such as expression".